# Scraping en python muestra un solo resultado

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

quiero extraer unos datos de una web, funciona bien, solo que arroja un solo resultado, hice otro que funciona bien y extrae todo, pero en este caso no. Alguna sugerencia. Saludos.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL_BASE = "http://www.lider.cl/electrohogar/category/Telefonía-y-Fotografía/Celulares-y-Teléfonos/Smartphones/_/N-1orftrb"
MAX_PAGES = 2000
counter = 0

for i in range(1, MAX_PAGES):

    if i > 1:
        url = "%spage/%d/" % (URL_BASE, i)
    else:
        url = URL_BASE

    req = requests.get(url)
    statusCode = req.status_code
    if statusCode == 200:

        html = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

        entradas = html.find_all('div', class_='col-md-10 col-sm-9 outcome template-listado col-iso-right')

        for entrada in entradas:
            counter += 1
            titulo = entrada.find('p', class_='name name-mosaico').getText()
            precio = entrada.find('p', class_='price').getText()


            print "%d - %s  |  %s " % (counter, titulo, precio, )

    else:
        break
```

el resultado que muestra:
1 - Samsung, Smartphone Galaxy J6 Negro Triangulado / Entel  |
$109.990
-39%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL_BASE ="https://www.lider.cl{}"
URL = URL_BASE.format("/electrohogar/category/Telefon%C3%ADa-y-Fotograf%C3%ADa/Celulares-y-Tel%C3%A9fonos/Smartphones/_/N-1orftrb")

# url de 120 resultados
#URL = URL_BASE.format("/electrohogar/category/Telefon%C3%ADa-y-Fotograf%C3%ADa/Celulares-y-Tel%C3%A9fonos/Smartphones/_/N-1orftrb?N=&No=0&Nrpp=120")

TOTAL=0

def mobiles(url,np=1):

    global TOTAL
    req = requests.get(url)
    statusCode = req.status_code

    if statusCode == 200:

        html = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
        # seleccionamos el contendor de los cels
        entradas = html.find('div', {"id": "content-prod-boxes"})

        # hacemos un loop por la info de  cada telefono
        for entrada in entradas.findAll("div",{"class":"box-product"}):
            # imagen
            img = entrada.find("img",{"class" : "photo img-responsive"})["src"]
            # extraemos el nombre
            name = entrada.find("p",{"class" : "name-mosaico"}).text
            # extraemos el precio y hacemos un split para obtener solo el precio sin el descuento
            price = entrada.find("p",{"class" : "price"}).text.split()[0]
            # imprimimos el resultado
            #print(img)
            print(f"{TOTAL:<4}{name:<70} {price}")
            TOTAL+=1


        try:
            # aumentamos en 1 el numero de pagina
            np+=1
            # concatenamos el page mas el numero de pagina
            number="&page="+str(np)
            # hacemos un loop del ul con classs pagination pull-right buscamos sus a href
            # validamos que exista el texto  &page= en x["href"] pasamos a lista y hacemos un set para eliminar los duplicados
            pagination = list(set([ x["href"] for x in html.find("ul",{"class" : "pagination pull-right"}).findAll("a",href=True) if number in x["href"]]))[0]
            # volvemos a llamar a la funcion con el nuevo numero de pagina
            mobiles(URL_BASE.format(pagination),np)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

mobiles(URL)
```

**resultado:**

```
0   Samsung, Smartphone Galaxy J6 Negro Triangulado / Entel                $109.990
1   Samsung, Smartphone J4+ Negro Triangulado / Entel                      $89.990
2   Samsung, Smartphone Galaxy J1 Negro / Movistar                         $49.990
3   Own, Smartphone Fun 6 Negro / Entel                                    $54.990
4   Samsung, Smartphone Galaxy J2 Prime Negro / Movistar                   $59.990
5   LG, Smartphone K9 Azul / Liberado                                      $69.990
6   Huawei, Smartphone Y5 2018 Negro / Entel                               $69.990
7   Nokia, Smartphone 2.1 Azul Triangulado / Entel                         $69.990
8   LG, Smartphone X Power II Negro / Liberado                             $79.990
9   Samsung, Smartphone Galaxy J2 Pro Dorado / Movistar                    $79.990
10  LG, Smartphone K11 Azul / Liberado                                     $79.990
11  Huawei, Smartphone Y6 2018 Dorado / Movistar                           $79.990
12  LG, Smartphone K11 Dorado / Liberado                                   $79.990
13  Huawei, Smartphone Y6 2018 Negro / Entel                               $79.990
14  Samsung, Smartphone J4+ Dorado Triangulado / Entel                     $89.990
15  LG, Smartphone Q6 Alpha Azul / Liberado                                $89.990
16  Xiaomi, Smartphone Note A5 Dorado / Liberado                           $99.990
17  Huawei, Smartphone Y7 2018 Negro / Entel                               $99.990
18  Xiaomi, Smartphone Note A5 Gris / Liberado                             $99.990
19  Samsung, Smartphone Galaxy J6 Dorado Triangulado / Entel               $109.990
20  Xiaomi, Smartphone Note A5 Prime Dorado / Liberado                     $119.990
21  Xiaomi, Smartphone Note A5 Prime Gris / Liberado                       $119.990
22  Xiaomi, Smartphone MIA 1 32 GB Dorado / Liberado                       $129.990
23  LG, Smartphone Q7 Negro / Liberado                                     $129.990
24  LG, Smartphone Q7 Lavanda / Liberado                                   $129.990
25  LG, Smartphone Q Stylus Negro / Liberado                               $149.990
26  Samsung, Smartphone J6+ Gris / Liberado                                $149.990
27  Samsung, Smartphone J6+ Negro / Liberado                               $149.990
28  Samsung, Smartphone Galaxy J8 Negro Triangulado / Movistar             $159.990
29  Samsung, Smartphone Galaxy J8 Dorado / Liberado                        $159.990
```

Comment: Gracias master!!